# Cucumber/Capybara: is it possible to mix xpath and css on the same command?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have an xpath expression that looks like this:

```
find(:xpath, "//div[@id='drawer-1' and @class='drawer']/h2/a[@class='drawer-toggle']")
```

I was wondering, is it possible to somehow mix this with css to read something like this?

```
find("div#drawer-1.drawer/h2/a.drawer-toggle")
```

Or if this is not possible, is there another way to navigate a DOM with css?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix xpath with css. However, in your example, the xpath can be translated to css.

You should be able to do:

```
find("div#drawer-1.drawer > h2 > a.drawer-toggle")
```

Note that the "/" are changed to ">". Xpath uses "/" as child selector, where as css uses ">".

A couple useful links:

- [Child selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)
- A [cheat sheet that compares xpath with css locators](http://www.natontesting.com/2011/09/24/css-locator-referencecheat-sheet-for-xpath-people/)

Comment: Nice one Justin, that's exactly what I was trying to understand. Much appreciated!

Comment: and do you know how I could do something similar to Xpath (//div[@id='first']//a[@id='link']).

like a double slash in the middle of the expression?

Comment: For the double slash, you want a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors), which is a space. So your example could be written as "div#first a#link", noting that the space between the two elements is the descendant selector.

Comment: Sorry for having troubled you with all these questions for beginners! Printing and studying the CSS link you sent me know...Cheers!